# Find last word in upper case from array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I`m dealing with a problem that I need to find last word in array which is in uppercase.

I already split all lines into words:

`string[] words = Regex.Split(e, sk);`

Was trying something like this

`z = words.Where(c => c == c.ToUpper().Last());`

but it doesn`t help anyhow..

Maybe someone has some suggestions?

Comment: What are `e` and `sk`?  There should probably be no need for regex here... If you are splitting on spaces anyways. Either way, regex is immaterial to the question if the desire is to find a word in an already split string (which is what `words` is). The solutions below would work for any `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 According to the task I must use regex.. 'e' is one line. In main function I read all lines and just use foreach to take each one. That`s because there is several more tasks I need to do so I need to take each line. 
'sk' is delimiter, string sk = "[\\s,.;:/?!()\\-]+";

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this LINQ-query:

```
z = words.Where(c =>c.All(Char.IsUpper)).Last();
```

or as suggested in another answer `LastOrDefault` to get `null` string if no one is complete in upper case.

Comment: 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'Last' and no extension method 'Last' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

This is what I`m getting

Comment: @Martin if you're using VS, there should be a "suggested fixes" thing (IIRC it's Ctrl+.) to automatically add the using directive

Comment: @Martin this query works, i have changed it a minute ago, perhaps you have tried out wrong version, do it again.

Comment: @MaksimSimkin everything looks good, but I keep getting error in console: Sequence contains no elements

Comment: @Martin What is your input?

Comment: When you created your array of words did you make sure to exclude the spaces and such like? I can imagine this will fail if there are trailing spaces (since the entire string isn't upper case characters).

Comment: @Chris I did, actually. Now the error gone but there is another problem.. When I split words and try to find the longest one, console prints only that word which has no delimiter next to it.. And now I have no idea what`s wrong because on another project I did the same split and finding var and it works, the only different that in successful project I use simple one line string, not txt file

Comment: @Martin: I'm not sure I follow what you mean. Probably best  to ask a new question rather than just asking in comments here.

Answer (score 3):

Your call to `Last()` should be outside of the lambda (see [Maksim Simkin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41533075/7366707).)

Would `words.LastOrDefault(c => c == c.ToUpper())` fit your needs? Since you need the last match.

There are probably better ways of detecting if a string is uppercase, for example `c.All(Char.IsUpper)`, so you could use

```
words.LastOrDefault(c => c.All(Char.IsUpper))
```

Comment: It's a great idea, to extend own answer copying  answer  below :)

Comment: You didn't quite copy it correctly. The other answer passes `Char.IsUpper` as a method group. Your example doesn't do that and would generate a compiler error. Either remove the extra parentheses or change it to something like `words.LastOrDefault(c => c.All(ch => char.IsUpper(ch)))`